# How to select non-consecutive rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

If the primary keys of the records are `1,3,4,5,6,8`

I want to select the records with pk:`1,6`

**NOTE**

I don't know which ids are non-consecutive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table AS a
    LEFT JOIN your_table AS b
        ON a.key_column = b.key_column - 1
WHERE b.key_column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [MyTable]
WHERE
    [MyId] NOT IN
(
    SELECT
        [MyId] - 1
    FROM
        [MyTable]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `where` clause in your SQL query ?

```
select *
from your_table
where id in (1, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, in your DB of choice, rows generally aren't "consecutive" unless you specifically ORDER them. They just often happen to come out in the right order when you don't specify an order by.

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement for the solution proposed by Robin Day

```
SELECT
    [MyId] + 1
FROM
    [MyTable]
WHERE
    [MyId] NOT IN
(
    SELECT
        [MyId] - 1
    FROM
        [MyTable]
)
ORDER BY [MyId] + 1
```